# i encounter error when trying to update my state

Tags: reactjs

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. 
This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. 
React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

i always encounter this error when ever i want to update my state in my react code

> state

```
    state = {
        total: 0,
        items:[10,20,30]

}
```

> function to sum the items and update my state

```
checkTotal() {
        let { items, total } = this.state;
    
        let itemTotal = itemObjectQuantity.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0);

        console.log(total);

        let totalObject = { total };

        let newTotal = { total: itemTotal };

        total = newTotal;
        this.setState({ total });
    //  console.log(totalObject);
    //  console.log(newTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mutating the state, if you want to update your state use setState to do so.
I am not sure that i understand what you are trying to do though.
If you want newTotal to be the next value of your total state, then use this.setState({total: newTotal}), if you want itemTotal to be the new value then use this.setState({total: itemTotal}).